# Анимация ожидания ответа ajax-запроса

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, анимация, css-animation

Можно ли сделать анимацию загрузки такую, как на этом видео: [тыЦ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93xKVYIsSTE).

Это анимация из samsung touchwiz android 5.0.

Как сделать такую на javascript или css3? И возможно ли сделать такую сложную? Например, с помощью css3 можно запилить вращающийся полукруг, на оси другого круга (2 div'a), но это не будет так круто, как на видео. Подкиньте своих идей для реализации.

Comment: @sanu0074, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Эм, видео на Flash, так что я посмотреть не могу его.

Вот здесь есть куча loader'ов: http://cssload.net/ru/

Можешь использовать как пример.

Все на CSS, без js,